# On geo nodes, radii of two nodes doesn't add up

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using two nodes, Star node and Fillet Curve to make a procedural Gear. I'm trying to offset the radii of both inputs so that my function would take an absolute value for the inner and outer radius for the gear spokes. However, the radii of the two nodes don't add up.  Here's the screenshot of my nodes. I tried multiplying and dividing the radius for the fillet curve before adding it into the Star node input but I'm not getting my desired effect. I'm pretty sure the solution for this is so embarrassingly easy.

[image: my nodes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to predict value because it hardly depends on angles of the star (Star is overlaid for illustrative purpose):

[image]

So I suggest moving points after filet, You can easily do this by scaling normalized position by radius:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Here is my solution for adjusting also gear teeth thickness:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is advanced stuff for me, no wonder I couldn't figure it out. I'm still starting to learn geometry nodes. Thank you very much for explaining it very well. I'm inspired even more to learn geometry nodes. 